# Multiple keywords in SELECT LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, implode

I have a search function on my site which uses GET. I have been trying to code something that would take words out of the GET post and then search in using SQL. This is what I been able to do:

```
$id = $_GET["search"];  
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $id);
$searchTermBits = array();
foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
    $term = trim($term);
    if (!empty($term)) {
        $searchTermBits[] = "Name LIKE '%$term%'"
    }
}

$lol = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE .implode(' AND ', $searchTermBits).")
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I get the following error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
 version for the right syntax to use near '(' AND ', Array).' at line 1
```

Comment: Are the terms all for Name of different columns ?

Comment: Set your SQL to the variable (`$lol = "SELECT...`), echo the variable (`echo $lol;`), and then send it to `mysql_query()`. What does it say when you echo it?

Comment: No, it's for the same column

Comment: @AmandaWood then you have another issue and should not use `AND` see my reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lol = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE .implode(' AND ', $searchTermBits).")
```

should be

```
$lol = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE ". implode(' AND ', $searchTermBits). "")
```

Answer (score 0):

`implode` is just a part of the string in your case, you need to take it out from quotes:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermBits))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using php implode function inside the double quote.place it outside the double quotes like this.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermBits))
```